# Trying to achieve dynamic lighting in a tiled 2D isometric environment using Java2D

Tags: java, game-engine, java-2d, lighting, isometric

I am trying write some lighting code for a Java2D isometric game I am writing - I have found a few algorithms I want to try implementing - one of which I found here:

[here](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/razorblades-isometric-dynamic-lighting-alg-r749)

The problem is that this sort of algorithm would require some optimal pixel-shading effect that I haven't found a way of achieving via Java2D. Preferably some method via the graphics hardware but if that isn't possible - at least a method of achieving the same effect quickly in software.

If that isn't possible, could someone direct me to a more optimal algorithm with Java2D in mind? I have considered per-tile lighting - however I find the drawPolygon method isn't hardware accelerated and thus performs very slowly.

I want to try and avoid native dependencies or the requirement for elevated permissions in an applet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a lot of research since I posted this question - there are tons of alternatives and JavaFX does intend (on a later release) to include its own shader language for those interested. There is also a ofcourse LWJGL that will allow you to load your own shaders onto the GPU.

However, if you're stuck in Java2D (as I am) it is still possible to implement lighting in an isometric game it is just 'awkward' because you cannot perform the light shading on a per-pixel level.

**How it Looks:**

I have achieved a (highly unpolished - after some polishing I can assure you it will look great) effect for casting shadows, depth sorting the light map, and applying the lighting without experiencing a drop in frame-rate. Here is how it looks:

[image: casting shadows and depth sorting the light map]

You'll see in this screen-shot a diffuse light (not shaded in but that step I'd say is relatively easy in contrast to the steps to get there) casting shadows - the areas behind the entities that obstructs the light's passage *BUT* also in the bounds of the light's maximum fall-out is shaded in as the ambient lighting but in reality this area is passed to the lights rendering routine to factor in the amount of obstruction that has occurred so that the light can apply a prettier gradient (or fading effect of some sort.)

The current implementation of the diffuse lighting is to just simply render obstructed regions the ambient colour and render non-obstructed regions the light's colour - obviously though you'd apply a fading effect as you got further from the light (that part of the implementation I haven't done yet - but as I said it is relatively easy.)

**How I did it:**
I don't guarantee this is the most optimal method, but for those interested:

Essentially, this effect is achieved by using a lot of Java shape operations - the rendering of the light map is accelerated by using a VolatileImage.

When the light map is being generated, the render routine does the following:

1. Creates an Area object that contains a Rectangle that covers the
   entirety of the screen. This area will contain your ambient
   lighting.
2. It then iterates through the lights asking them what their
   light-casting Area would be if there were no obstructions in the way.
3. It takes this area object and searches the world for Actors\Tiles
   that are contained within that area that the light would be cast in.
4. For every tile that it finds that obstructs view in the light's casting area, it will calculate the difference in the light source's position and the obstruction's
   position (essentially creating a vector that points *AT* the
   obstruction from the light source - this is the direction you want to cast your shadow) This pointing vector (in world
   space) needs to be translated to screen space.
5. Once that has been done, a perpendicular to that vector is taken and
   normalized. This essentially gives you a line you can travel up or
   down on by multiplying it by any given length to travel the given direction in. This vector is
   perpendicular to the direction you want to cast your shadow over.
6. Almost done, you consturct a polygon that consists of four points.
   The first two points are at the the base of the screen coordinate of
   your obstruction's center point. To get the first point, you want to
   travel up your perpendicular vector (calculated in 5) a quantity of
   half your tile's height [ this is a relatively accurate
   approximation though I think this part of the algorithm is slightly
   incorrect - but it has no noticable decay on the visual effect] -
   then ofcourse add to that the obstructions origin. To get the
   second, you do the same but instead travel down.
7. The remainder of the two points are calculated exactly the same way -
   only these points need to be projected outward in the direction of
   your shadow's projection vector calculated in 4. - You can choose any large amount to project it outwards by - just as long as it reaches at least outside of you light's casting area (so if you just want to do it stupidly multiply your shadow projection vector by a factor of 10 and you should be safe)
8. From this polygon you just constructed, construct an area, and then
   invoke the "intersect" method with your light's area as the first
   argument - this will assure that your shadows area doesn't reach
   outside of the bounds of the area that your light casts over.
9. Subtract from your light's casting the shadow area you constructed
   above. At this point you now have two areas - the area where the
   light casts unobstructed, and the area the light casts over
   obstructed - if your Actors have a visibility obstruction factor
   that you used to determine that a particular actor was obstructing
   view - you also have the grade at which it obstructs the view that
   you can apply later when you are drawing in the light effect (this will allow you to chose between a darker\brighter shade depending on how much light is being obstructed
10. Subtract from your ambient light area you constructed in (1) both
     the light area, and the obstructed light area so you don't apply
     the ambient light to areas where the lighting effect will take over
     and render into

**Now you need to merge your light map with your depth-buffered world's render routine**

Now that you've rendered you're light map and it is contained inside of a volatile image, you need to throw it into your world's render routine and depth-sorting algorithm. Since the back-buffer and the light map are both volatileimages, rendering the light map over the world is relatively optimal.

You need to construct a polygon that is essentially a strip that contains what a vertical strip of your world tiles would be rendered into (look at my screen shot, you'll see an array of thin diagonal lines seperating these strips. These strips are what I am referring). You can than render parts of this light map strip by strip (render it over the strip after you've rendered the last tile in that strip since - obviously - the light map has to be applied *over* the map). You can use the same image-map just use that strip as a clip for Graphics - you will need to translate that strip polygon down per render of a strip.

Anyway, like I said I don't guarantee this is the most optimal way - but so far it is working fine for me.
The light map is applied p